# How do I check the top index (index 0) in ListView?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

How do I check on the `ListView`, if I click on  index 0 (top) then my button will be enabled, but if I click other than index 0 (1, 2, 3, …) the button will be disabled (i.e., `Enabled = false`).

This is my current code:

```
private void lstAntrianPasien_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (lstAntrianPasien.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
    {
        btnUbahStatus.Enabled = true;
    }
    else
    {
        btnUbahStatus.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [SelectedIndices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.selectedindices.aspx) property:

```
btnUbahStatus.Enabled = lstAntrianPasien.SelectedIndices.Count == 1
                        && lstAntrianPasien.SelectedIndices[0] == 0;
```

Alternately, if you want the button to be enabled if the first item is selected, regardless of the selection state of the other items, you can use [Contains()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.selectedindexcollection.contains.aspx):

```
btnUbahStatus.Enabled = lstAntrianPasien.SelectedIndices.Contains(0);
```